# jquery load function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unable to get this piece of code working. I am running this on xampp. The alert works fine but the html wont load. Please help.

I have added the links to jquery 3.2.1

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttonClick").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
    $("#viable").load('new_123.html');
});
});
</script>
```

**New_123.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello 123</h1>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: where is the DOM with `viable` id

Comment: Do you get any errors in the brower's console? If you check the Browser's Dev Tools *Network* tab do you see the expected HTML being returned?

Comment: please add appropriate code for the used elements

Comment: I am unable to see any html element with id `buttonClick`? so how it will work.it will not work

Comment: You shouldn't have `<html>` and `<body>` tags in the HTML that you're loading, since that should already be in the current page.

Comment: are you running your code in your localhost server ?

Comment: Guys... Found the issue. Yes i am running this in my localhost server and my browser console was throwing a cross origin error. Found a way to handle that and got it working ! Thanks everyone! I am still confused as to why i am getting the cross origin error. This hardly qualifies as cross origin!

Answer (score 4):

Your body tag is missing a closing bracket `">"`.

Comment: It need to be a comment . And it seems TYPO mistake not the actual cause of problme. So the answer is not useful at all.

Comment: Interesting, im new to stackoverflow and now starting to understand the culture behind it... will keep on contributing selectively and carefully

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting this as an answer if you think it will solve the OP's problem. But if you just wanted to point out an incidental issue not related to the main problem then it should be posted as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same code and i mgetting the result properly May be that **'>'** is an issue!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#buttonClick").click(function(){
           var d= $("#viable").load('b.html');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viable"></div>
    <button id="buttonClick"></button>
</body>
</html>
```